# Apex:repeat on a dataTable column

Tags: apex, repeat

I've been working on creating a table that will sit on an Opportunity page. I want to have the results group into months that repeat as the columns in a data table. I think that I need to use apex:repeat on the date but I can't seem to figure out how to do this.

Is there a way to iterate a query into separate columns instead of using fields as the column?

Here is what I have thus far:

vf page:

```
<apex:page controller="Opportunity_RevScheduleController" id="thePage" showHeader="false" sidebar="false">
 <apex:pageBlock title="Pipeline Revenue Schedule">
  <apex:dataTable value="{!revSchedule}" var="revSch" cellPadding="4" border="1">
     <apex:column value="{!revSch.Name}"/>
     <apex:column value="{!revSch.Revenue_Pipeline__r.Total_Schedule__c}"/>
     <apex:column value="{!revSch.Revenue_Pipeline__r.opportunity__c}"/>
     <apex:column value="{!revSch.Date__c}" />
     <apex:repeat value="{!revSch.Date__c}" var="date">
        <apex:column value="{!revSch.Amount__c}" />
     </apex:repeat>
  </apex:dataTable>
</apex:pageBlock>
```

controller:

```
public with sharing class Opportunity_RevScheduleController {
List<Revenue_Pipeline_Schedule__c> revSchedule;

String oppId = Apexpages.currentPage().getParameters().get('OpportunityId');

public List<Revenue_Pipeline_Schedule__c> getrevSchedule() {
    if(revSchedule == null)
        revSchedule = [SELECT Name,
                           Date__c,
                           Amount__c,
                           Revenue_Pipeline__r.Total_Schedule__c,
                           Revenue_Pipeline__r.Opportunity__c
                    FROM Revenue_Pipeline_Schedule__c 
                    Where Revenue_Pipeline__r.Opportunity__c = '0066C000002HnDz'];
    return revSchedule;
}
}
```

Comment: You're going to need to use a wrapper class.

Comment: The `value` of the `apex:repeat` needs to be a collection not a single value. Suggest you work on the required [aggregate query](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.apexcode.meta/apexcode/langCon_apex_SOQL_agg_fns.htm) first and then the UI after.